# I am glad to hear you are recovered

Tags: sentence-usage

Is it correct to say

> I am glad to hear that you are recovered from...

What else can I say even if it is correct to say?

Comment: The correct phrase would be "have recovered" instead of "are recovered"

Comment: It's not uncommon to hear some native English speakers using the verb **to be** in such contexts, instead of the conventional **have**. You will come across constructions like: **They are sat over there** and **She was took ill**. (Not that I'm promoting them!)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @ThisIsAQuestion, the correct grammar is

> I am glad to hear that you **have** recovered from...

Another way to say it is

> I am glad to hear you are **better**.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/better) has

> **better**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **2** Partly or fully recovered from illness, injury, or mental stress.
> *Wishing both a great time and hoping that Jim's hand injury will soon get better.*